# How to update the order column using single update statement while order changed

Tags: mysql

**lets assume below is the current state of the table 'test_group':**

```
mysql> select * from test_group;

+----+------------+---------------+
| id | group_name | display_order |
+----+------------+---------------+
|  1 | A          |             1 |
|  2 | B          |             2 |
|  3 | C          |             3 |
|  4 | D          |             4 |
|  5 | E          |             5 |
+----+------------+---------------+
```

**Now, I want to insert the record with order 5 before order 3,
So revised table should look like below** :

```
mysql> select * from test_group;

+----+------------+---------------+
| id | group_name | display_order |
+----+------------+---------------+
|  1 | A          |             1 |
|  2 | B          |             2 |
|  3 | C          |             4 |
|  4 | D          |             5 |
|  5 | E          |             3 |
+----+------------+---------------+
```

**The original order like below** :

```
group_name "A" is NO.1
group_name "B" is NO.2
group_name "C" is NO.3
group_name "D" is NO.4
group_name "E" is NO.5
```

**Now, I want to insert the record with order 5 before order 3, so the modified order like below**:

```
group_name "A" is NO.1
group_name "B" is NO.2
group_name "E" is NO.3
group_name "C" is NO.4
group_name "D" is NO.5
```

**My sql statement like below :**

```sql
update
    test_group
set
    display_order =(case
        when display_order >= 3
        and display_order <5 then display_order + 1
        when id = 5 then 3
        else display_order
    end)
where
    display_order in (3,4,5);
```

**Although my sql statement can be successfully executed, is there a better way, I think my statement is very stupid**

Comment: Please explain the logic here.

Comment: Show complete CREATE TABLE for your table. provide precise MySQL version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
UPDATE test
SET pos = CASE pos WHEN @pos_from THEN @pos_to
                   ELSE pos + SIGN(@pos_from - @pos_to)
                   END
WHERE pos BETWEEN LEAST(@pos_from, @pos_to) AND GREATEST(@pos_from, @pos_to);
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=62e7d8639079fa683bddd04309580259) with some comments.

PS. The query does not check the positions values values. You may add this if needed.

Comment: Thank you very much, can I write my sql statement like this? Although it also works. But I think there must be a more efficient sql statement。

Comment: @soonbeer *I think there must be a more efficient sql statement* ??? o_O Point me to this solution inefficiency. The only improvement (and I doubt that it can improve really) is to move all 3 constant expressions to the subquery.

Comment: Sorry, there is a misunderstanding here, I am saying that the sql statement I wrote is very inefficient

Answer (score 0):

**Although my sql statement can be successfully executed, is there a better way, I think my statement is very stupid**

```sql
update
    test_group
set
    display_order =(case
        when display_order >= 3
        and display_order <5 then display_order + 1
        when id = 5 then 3
        else display_order
    end)
where
    display_order in (3,4,5);
```

**this is okay too :**

```sql
update
    test_group
set
    display_order = if(display_order =
    #{posFrom}, #{posTo}, display_order + SIGN(#{posFrom} - #{posTo}))
where
    display_order between LEAST(#{posFrom}, #{posTo}) and GREATEST(#{posFrom}, #{posTo});
```

Comment: *when id = 5 then 3* Obviously incorrect. You mix identifier and ordering value.